# Send response after rest authentication fails

Tags: rest, jersey

I have over-ridden ContainerRequestFilters by class A and ContainerResponseFilters by Class B.

Now whenever there is a rest call, class A gets the request first and then it goes to another class, Class C.

The flow is, request comes to Class A, then it goes to class C and finally to Class B.

Now when I see that something is not good and I need to send a response, how can I do it from class A. I need to bypass class C.

Comment: Why don't you throw an exception and process it with ExceptionMapper?

Comment: Great. It worked. Thanks a lot Justas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw exception and catch it in your main class or using `ExceptionMapper` - [Return exception from JAX-RS Rest Service as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467648/return-exception-from-jax-rs-rest-service-as-json/36468247#36468247).