# Get stack trace of Exception through spring rest template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have 2 services - `Service 1` and `Service 2`. `Service 1` calls some `Service 2`  API through Spring Rest Template. Now Some exception happened in `Service 2`. I need the whole stack trace of it in `Service 1`. How to get it ?

```
Service 1  ---calls--> Service 2
```

Does the stack trace even get passed to `Service 1` by Spring ?

You can say I am calling like this :

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
return restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/products", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class).getBody();
```

Comment: [distributed tracing](https://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin). get the logs based on trace id from centralized logging solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need the whole stack trace of it in Service 1. How to get it ?

So there are ways to get it , **in essence you have to implement.**
You can get your relevant exception message/trace in `JSON response` from `Service 2` . That is , when there is any `exception` at `Service 2` end then , we can configure response to send relevant exception information.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22271099/convert-exception-to-json) post there are **3 answers** explaining different ways to achieve, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467648/return-exception-from-jax-rs-rest-service-as-json) one. Now on  :

> Does the stack trace even get passed to Service 1 by Spring ?

Normally any unhandled/runtime `exception` thrown when processing a `web-request` causes the server to return an `HTTP 500` response.

So the answer **is spring does not transfer the stack trace to `Service 1`** rather respond with error `HTTP 500` and the most likely message of your `exception`.

However, any exception that you write yourself can be annotated with the `@ResponseStatus` annotation (which supports all the HTTP status codes defined by the `HTTP` specification).

When an `annotated exception` is thrown from a controller method, and not handled elsewhere, it will automatically cause the appropriate `HTTP response` to be returned with the specified status-code and with the message/trace written.
For example,

```
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="No such Account")  // 404
public class AddressNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    // ...
}
```

And here is a controller method using it:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/{id}", method=GET)
public String showOrder(@PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) {
    Account account = accountServices.findAccountById(id);

    if (account == null) throw new AddressNotFoundException(id);
    model.addAttribute(account);
    return "accountDetail";
}
```

A familiar `HTTP 404` response will be returned if the URL handled by this method includes an unknown account id.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

To **summarize** a straight-forward approach it is not much more than adding Spring Boot's `Zipkin` and `Sleuth` starters into your `pom.xml`s to enable log tracing in both directions between multiple apps…

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-sleuth.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

…and configure your log pattern in your `application.properties` to reflect the `SpanId`s and `TraceId`s which Sleuth injected in your requests…

```
logging.pattern.level=[%X{X-B3-TraceId}/%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n
```

You can also compare your own progress with a running example on [Openzipkin's Github account](https://github.com/openzipkin/sleuth-webmvc-example).

Maybe you could give it a try and show us your experiences and progress with it!

Answer (score 1):

1) Catch specific HttpServerErrorException and HttpClientErrorException before 
       Exception, propagate exception object all the way up to service 1 or 
       resource.

```
try {
 //code
} catch (HttpServerErrorException | HttpClientErrorException ex) {
throw new SystemException("Http Exception", ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), 
ex);
} catch (RuntimeException ex) {
throw new SystemException("RuntimeException", ex);
} catch (Exception ex) {
throw new SystemException("default exception block", ex);
}
```

2) Have Exception mapper like below for your system and business exceptions 
       where all the error messages can be caught and logged.

```
   public class SystemException extends Throwable implements
        ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

      @Override
      public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
         //code to handle exception
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert that exception in Service1 into string and attach that exception string to response with an error code, try to catch that exception in your Service2
By using the below code u can convert exception to string

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
String exceptionString = stringWriter.toString();
System.out.println(exceptionString);
```

In your Catch block of service1

```
return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
            .body(exceptionString);
```

or

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(
      exceptionString, 
      HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 1):

when service 2 get exception it will return http 500 so you cant see any detail on service 1 , so you have to intercept exception on @controlleradvice  , create a controller advice and set runtime or any exception with specific http status and stack trace as error detail return it .

```
@ControllerAdvice
    public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
      extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

        @ExceptionHandler(value 
          = { Service2Exception.class})
        protected ResponseEntity<Service2Error> handleService2Exception(
          RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
            String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
             Service2Error error = new Service2Error();
              error.setStack(toStack(ex));
            return new ResponseEntity<Server2Error>(error,HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);// what you want
        }
    }
        public static String toStack(Exception e) {
             StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
             PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
             e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
             String exceptionString = stringWriter.toString();
             return exceptionString;
       }
}


      public class Service2Error {
                private String errorStack;
                private int errorCode;
                         // getter settter


       }
```